# Is it possible to hide one's presence from the DHCP client list

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I ask because I recently changed my WiFi password after seeing some unfamiliar devices in the DHCP client list.

After that, the client list only has familiar names now, but there is still some inexplicable behavior in the network (network getting congested when it shouldn't. WiFi router blinking some lights that shouldn't be blinking (didn't before), etc).

These problems MAY be coming from other sources, but I just want to make sure that it is NOT possible for an intruder to hide himself/herself from the DHCP client list, before moving on to other issues.

Comment: They can, by simply assigning themselves static IP. DHCP client list will only list clients requesting DHCP. Besides changing your WiFi Password, make sure you are using WPA2 on your WiFi rather than WEP.

Answer (score 1):

If they assign themselves a static IP then they will not be seen on the DHCP client list. Are you not able to see them on any other part of the router management interface such as a summary of all devices connected? There is a possibility of them doing the following:

Your only real chance of getting close to hiding would be to run a rouge DHCP server that hands out address on a different subnet to the existing one, ensuring to fudge the mac address of the DHCP responses to match the current routers mac address. To an IDS or watcher of some nature it will appear that the router has gone nuts and is now running two DHCP servers as both DHCP responses will show up. Unless the IDS is the router, as it will see that the responses are coming from a port on the switch rather than it's self.

So, once a client has used your response for DHCP as it's address, you have your computer clone that clients mac address and hostname and send a DHCP request to the router and get a real IP address on the network. Then some simple NAT routing will allow the client who you stole the identity of to still function. This will create inconsistency in the network but should function correctly. The main inconsistency been that one mac address has two different IP addresses and are on two different ports of a switch. The other clients on the network should be fine with this as they arn't in the subnet as one of the addresses, the router might not as your computer will constantly be trying to communicate with the client to get it's nat'ed traffic to it. Might also want to setup a DMZ and put the cloned client in the DMZ so that file sharing (and the like) will still work for it.

Comment: The DHCP client list is the only such summary I can see in the router's admin page. The DHCP workaround you mentioned COULD be why I'm seeing weird behavior with the router. Is there any way I can find said "rogue" DHCP servers and shut them down? I could manage to navigate a Terminal-based process for shutting them down, if there is a detailed-enough walkthrough. Thank you!