# How can I find any additional DHCP servers that may have been installled on my network by an intruder?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

See this question for background:
[Is it possible to hide one's presence from the DHCP client list](https://superuser.com/questions/829986/is-it-possible-to-hide-ones-presence-from-the-dhcp-client-list)

nmap finds all connected clients for me, and I haven't had any trouble on this front since changing my passwords, etc.

But my router still behaves strangely (disconnecting randomly, etc) which didn't happen before the intrusion. So I suspect some remnants of the intrusion are still left. Perhaps a rogue DHCP server as mentioned in the previous question.

But how do I find such a server? Or should nmap have found one if it existed?

P.S: On looking at the services running on the router, I found - apart from the normal TCP/IP thing - an "eDonkey" server. This seems like completely outdated tech, so it's possible it shipped with the router (a Belkin N150 model) by default. Or could it be something an intruder could have used? If so, I'll ask a separate question on shutting it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to track DHCP servers is to issue a DHCP request and look at what replies.

This is easiest from a Linux box, but you can do it from a Windows machine too.

For both linux and Windows, you can use wireshark to monitor the relevant interface filtered for udp port 67-68

For Windows, switch to a static ip, then to a dhcp ip. This will trigger a dhcp request:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

For linux, you can (make sure NetworkManager or any other network management services aren't running):

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 up
dhclient eth0
```

Then watch what happens in wireshark.  You should see the DHCP request go out as a broadcast, then a series of IP addresses will send a response.

EDonkey is filesharing software, often used for pirating data.  There is very little chance this was installed or enabled on your router by the vendor.

Comment: Under Windows, it will be sufficient if the commands "ipconfig /release" and "ipconfig /renew" are issued.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the OS - it's OSX. I suppose the same commands would work, and that some "Network Management" service will be running. In that case, would simply turning off and turning back on the WiFi adapter, achieve the same effect?

Comment: I tried all 3 - using this approach, turning WiFi off and on again, and finally the DHCPLOC tool recommended by @theoriginalzads in his answer. This confirms that a rogue DHCP server is not the source of my troubles. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

An application such as dhcploc.exe will assist in finding DHCP servers that are hiding on your network.

[DHCPLOC Utility on Microsoft Technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DHCPLOC-Utility-34262d82)

Comment: I can spin up the Windows PC, but is there a Mac/Unix equivalent for this tool? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this tip - I'll plus-1 later when I have enough rep.

Comment: `ipconfig getoption en0 server_identifier` for OS X, having no experience with Unix, I'd assume it's the same.